# putting value to nullable variable

Tags: c#, .net

How is the best to do following 
Booking Address is a structure

```
BookingAddress? retval= null;
```

here comes my logic and ihave following

```
BookingAddress address = new BookingAddress(reelinfo.LineID, reelinfo.McID);
retval = address;
```

Is there more nice way to put the needed value to the retVal ?

Comment: There are more meaningful names than `retval`. I know it stands for "return value" but you're returning a booking address, not a return value.

Comment: I like using a variable called `result` to hold the return value. And in short functions it carries enough meaning, especially since its type is already `BookingAddress`

Comment: Sidenote: You might want to consider making `BookingAddress` a class

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply:

```
BookingAddress? retval = new BookingAddress(reelinfo.LineID, reelinfo.McID);
```

A non nullable value type is implicitly convertible to the corresponding nullable value-type.

```
BookingAddress? retval= null;
if(...)
  retval = new BookingAddress(reelinfo.LineID, reelinfo.McID);
```

Comment: I just want to return a null object if i not enter my logic code.

Comment: @nightwalker That doesn't make a difference. You can always assign `T` to `Nullable<T>`

Comment: @Pabuc I don't understand what you want. If I don't declare retval as it can't be null. Of course I could rewrite the function to use a `return null` and a `return new BookAddress(...)` but that doesn't answer the OPs question.

Answer (score 2):

What about just:

```
retval = new BookingAddress(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
return new BookingAddress(reelinfo.LineID, reelinfo.McID);
```

You don't really need the `retval` variable if you are not doing anything with it between assigining its value and returning it.